# How to negate Bash's Regular Expression Matching Operator

Tags: bash, regular-expression, pattern-matching

Bash has the `=~` regular expression matching operator. [Here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/bashver3.html#REGEXMATCHREF) is an example of using it:

```
#!/bin/bash

input=$1


if [[ "$input" =~ "[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]" ]]
#                 ^ NOTE: Quoting not necessary, as of version 3.2 of Bash.
# NNN-NN-NNNN (where each N is a digit).
then
  echo "Social Security number."
  # Process SSN.
else
  echo "Not a Social Security number!"
  # Or, ask for corrected input.
fi
```

For negation, all the examples I have seen rely on an `else` clause. For situations where I am *only* interested in negative matches, is there a better way that making a non-functional `if` clause?

For example, if I only cared about the case where the above input is **not** a Not a Social Security number, what is the right way to go about this?

Comment: If you're expecting `$input` to be *only* a SSN, consider anchoring the regex -- `^[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$`; otherwise input such as `a555-44-99991` would match.

Comment: @JeffSchaller SSN's are only from the stock example. I'm not using SSN's.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can negate at the top level:

```
if ! [[ …
```

Comment: I guess implementing `!~` was too hard to disambituate from history expansion.